# Loop asLongAs() in Gatling using Scala

Tags: css, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

`I am trying to use a loop e.g. asLongAs() in Galing but not getting enough data on google about how to use.
My scenrio is to open a HTML page and that page takes some time to load and for that I have a css selector to check that once the report get loaded we have one css selector to check in the source code.
my code is like:

```
`exec (http("ABC -${ID} - Id -${ID2}")
.get("web/a/b/c/")
.check(css(.abc).saveAs("URL"))
.exec(session =\> {
val response = session("URL").as\[String\]
println(s"url is: \\n$response")
session
})
exec(http("Open the redirected report - ${ID1} Id-${ID2}")
.get(session =\> session("URL").as\[String\])
Some checks
.check(css(".Image").exists)`
```

I want to create a loop till this css(.Image) is loading. Because once the URL is hitting at that time this CSS doesn't appear and it takes time to load and i want to calculate that time only.

Answer (score 0):

> but not getting enough data on google

Have you tried the official documentation ? It has samples for Java, Scala and Kotlin.
https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#aslongas

Comment: I saw this document already but not getting any examples so that i can fit that in my code.

Comment: @Stefan, in this document there are no examples its showing only syntax and that is not helping me.